# Xamarin - Unit Test App (android) - defining usage

Tags: android, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android

Today I have been looking at **Unit Test App (Android)** for our Xamarin Android app.

[image]

However lack of any official documentation and proper explanation left me very inconclusive of how to actually use this => **what to test with it**?

I understand that for UI Tests we have the **UI Test App**. For our PCL/Share Class library that contains some business logic I use just a standard NUnit project.

Is the **"Unit Test App (Android)** project meant to be used as:

1. If I have an "Android Class Library", reference it there and test code that is contained there?
2. Reference an Android project and then with some magic, test the code that is contained there? (although I can't really imagine how that would work)
3. Something else that I haven't thought of.

This is an example of some tests in the **Unit Test App (Android)** project. I hope you can agree that this is a very inconclusive example:

```
   [TestFixture]
    public class TestsSample
    {

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup() { }


        [TearDown]
        public void Tear() { }

        [Test]
        public void Pass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1");
            Assert.True(true);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Fail()
        {
            Assert.False(true);
        }

        [Test]
        [Ignore("another time")]
        public void Ignore()
        {
            Assert.True(false);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Inconclusive()
        {
            Assert.Inconclusive("Inconclusive");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to read up on `Nunit for Devices` : https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin Your "app" is a device specific shell that is able to run Nunit tests thus it can access device-specific SDKs, like GPS, etc... but it is ***not*** for UI testing. Thus `Nunit` for platform *independent* testing, `Nunit|Xunit for  Devices` for platform specific testing that involves platform-specfic SDK access, and `UITest` for  GUI testing on devices

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you for your input, however you basically described what I described, UI Test project for UI Testing but the Test App Project for what? I would love to see some examples of how it's being used. I can't find anything except for a few console write lines and asserting trues :)

Comment: As I said, `Test App Project` are shell apps. They contain an NUnit runner so you can preform `[Test]`'s that are **device specific**. Anything that you are testing the you need to confirm on the actual platform can be tested. Example, you want to test your `HttpClient` routines in an actaul Android/iOS device (or simulator), enable and access GPS location events, start your custom Android service and send it Broadcast events, etc...

Comment: As an example, I have an Android `Service` that performs image optimizations in the background in a few of my apps. I have that `Service` which includes an embedded `BroadcastReceiver` packaged in an Android library. Using `Nunit for Devices` I can include that project and start the service and send it broadcasts and monitor the results within Nunit-based tests.

Comment: @SushiHangover I see, thanks for it, I think I am a bit clearer on it now. Could you maybe form this into an answer with a simple example and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Did you ever get any examples or have any examples of testing useful code int the test app? I think I am having the same issue you had I can't seem to find any useful examples all the examples/tutorials use simple asserts. @SushiHangover I would love to see at least one simple example of you testing the service you referenced.

Comment: @OmarRodriguez To be honest, no, not really. I gave up on this as it would mean heavily re-structuring our app project. Basically extract all meaningful mobile-platform dependent logic to the Android test project. We already have some UI tests and doing this would mean running two simulator/device dependent test projects. For us it's not worth it at this moment as our main business logic lies in PCL projects. That might be also the reason for lack of examples.. just hard to justify the true value of it while bringing extra complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to quote [JohnathanPryor](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29203/unit-testing-with-android-unit-test-project-in-xamarin-forms) from Xamarin to answer your question:

> Don't add Application projects to Application projects; things
> generally won't work as you expect.

Instead...

> Because adding Application projects as project references to
> Application projects is (still!) not advised (at least until using
> Wear project support), this was never a good way to unit test your
> code.
>
> Thus, what you should instead do is place any code you want to have
> used by a Unit Test Project be within an Android Library (or PCL)
> project. This will ensure that the type you're testing can use Android
> Resources "normally", have things generally work as expected and
> desired, and your code will be usable by both the Unit Test project
> and the Application project you really care about.

Again, quoting that thread, one of the possible solutions is

> MyProj (Solution)
>
> - MyProj (PCL)
> - MyProj.Android (default Xamarin project)
> - MyProj.Android.Shared (Android Class Library)
> - MyProj.Android.Test> (Android Unit Test App)
> - MyProj.iOS (default Xamarin project)
>
> Where MyProj.Android contains almost nothing and MyProj.Android.Shared
> contains everything (Activities/Bundles et all) so that they can be
> referenced in the Android unit tests

or

using a [Shared Project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess it still doesn't answer my question of an example "what to test with it".

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Android Unit Test project has it's own UI and allows you to run your Unit Tests while executing on the actual platform, i.e. on an actual Android device or emulator. The UI is very simple and juts allows for starting the unit tests and seeing the results. And yes you can reference an Android class library and I would imagine an Android app project as well.

Here's a good blog post on the subject: https://medium.com/@_kbremner/automating-android-unit-tests-with-xamarin-6058d101eb97#.5t77lbvzd

Comment: I don't think you can reference actual Android App project. I tried it and when it was compiling it threw many errors related to missing resources etc. so I think it's just meant for Android libraries, not actual Android App projects.